# How to recover a BIOS password?

Tags: bios, passwords, password-recovery, phoenix

Specifically a Phoenix BIOS password.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [CmosPwd](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/CmosPwd) from http://www.cgsecurity.org/

If that doesn't work, there's sometimes a 'backdoor' password built in to the BIOS. Try `BIOS`, `CMOS`, `phoenix`, `PHOENIX`.

Finally, there might be a BIOS reset button or jumper on the motherboard. Or take the CMOS battery out for a while.

Comment: Cool tried out the 'backdoor' passwords and one did work. That is a thing I will remember lol. upvoted

Answer (score 2):

you can't really 'recover' a BIOS password, either you find the aforementioned backdoor/universal password for this particular BIOS (not all of them have one.) or you'll have to reset the CMOS which will clear the BIOS password. refer to your mainboard manual.

Comment: There is often a "Restore CMOS settings" jumper that has to be installed to make this happen

Comment: some manufacturers of older mainboards were using 'dip switches' for that.

Answer (score 0):

BIOS' sometimes have backdoor passwords.  Some that may have been used for a Pheonix bios include: BIOS, CMOS, phoenix, and PHOENIX

Alternatively, you could open the computer and remove the CMOS battery, as well as physically unplug the computer, then wait a minute.  This should reset the BIOS to factory defaults.

Comment: Agree. That may save him from removing the battery, but he still cannot actually recover the password.

Comment: Also, most modern mb's have a jumper for resetting the bios. Saves you from removing the battery (although, finding it sometimes takes more time ...